# Trigonometric functions of multiple variable

Tags: functional-analysis, trigonometry, vector-spaces

Let's say we have the function $f :\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, $f(x) = \cos(x+y)$. So a function that takes the tuple $(x,y)$ and outputs $\cos(x+y)$.

Do the formulas like $\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$ still make sense but in this version $\cos(x+y)^2 + \sin(x+y)^2 = 1$ ?

The formulas made sense with the vision of a trigonometric circle but what happens if there are $2$ variables involved? I don't seem to understand how would that work..

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

For all(!) real numbers $a$ we have

$\cos^2(a)+\sin^2(a)=1$.

If $x,y \in \mathbb R$, then put $a=x+y$ , hence

$\cos^2(x+y)+\sin^2(x+y)=1$.

If $A,l,e,x,n,d,r,a \in \mathbb R$, then

$\cos^2(A+l+e+x+a+n+d+r+a)+\sin^2(A+l+e+x+a+n+d+r+a)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is applicable for any number of real variables.
Number of variables in the bracket doesn't matter as long you take the sine and cosine of the same variables! 
I have used a very layman language to keep it easy.
Hope this helps!